# Prevent Visual Studio from removing space after i element using bootstrap and ASP MVC Razor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

I am using ASP MVC with Razor view engine and also use Bootstrap template in my web application.
In many places in my application I use the `<i>` element to show an icon.

The problem is when I format a view VS2012 remove the trailing space after the `<i>` element and the actual test which make the page look bad.

Is there a way to configure VS2012 to leave that space?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting. Click the 'Tag Specific' button in that window and you should be able to edit the formatting for tags, including i.

Comment: Thank you, I found this options, but there was no way to configure spaces before and after tag, only line brakes.